# Can I use the square of correlation from copula to calculate the R square (co-efficient of determination)?

Tags: distributions, r-squared, copula

I have two variables, security returns, and market returns. I want to calculate R-Squared from copula correlations. What is the possible way to calculate the R-Square from the copula of these two variables? Moreover, Which Copula is best fitted for these variables?

Comment: Selecting the best fit copula is not straightforward. You can deal with this point using `BiCopselect()` function in `VineCopula`. For the R-squrared correlation, I do not this you can do this with copula.